# Create hotkey for webapp - mapped to menu item

Tags: automation, hotkeys

I need to create a hotkey to select a menu item on a webapp. This is a drop down menu in the application page itself not a browser menu.

**Details:**
[ From my somewhat limited knowledge of javascript/html/css ]

From looking at the source it appears that the buttons are YAHOO.widget.Button styled li + a tags.

I can see the id of the element I wish to map a hotkey to. Is this something Autoit or AutoHotkey could do ...or are there better/easier ways? I don't want to send tabs and enter etc if avoidable. Can I directly access this element and trigger it with a hotkey?

**Other:**
Firefox or Chrome on Windows 7 ( IE not compatible with the app so not an option ).

Thanks!

Comment: Greasemonkey may be a good option, since it'll be dom-aware.

Comment: @Frank Farmer ~ Will check into Greasemonkey. At first glance it seems perfect for the task.

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes to Frank Farmer who answers in the comments above.

Greasemonkey will work for this and is vastly superior to AutoIt/AutoHotKey as I now have a cross-platform solution for our Mac and Linux users. And besides, why learn another language of limited use when you can just use JavaScript?

Thanks Frank!